# Why don't Linux utils use a system call to get the current time?

Tags: linux, clock, syscalls

I'm really trying to understand why our guest VMs aren't using the kvm-clock driver "like they're supposed to". They're running RHEL 7.2, glibc-2.17, kern 3.10.0.  Programs such as `date` and `perl -e 'print time'` get the current time, but do so without making a system call. This is confirmed with strace and ltrace and further confirmed by using gdb and tracing through assembly which bypassed the `syscall` and instead executed some instruction called `rtdscp`.

Is this an attempt at optimization by the glibc authors? Is there any way to disable this and force glibc calls to make the systemcall (short of LD_PRELOAD hacks)?

**UPDATE** 2016-10-14:

After reviewing the latest [POSIX draft](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/clock_gettime/), part of the answer is clear: there is a way to request the clock from the CPU, but GNU glibc has wrongly forced this implementation on its users. The work-around is to invoke the system call directly. (Booooh)

> If _POSIX_CPUTIME is defined, implementations shall support clock ID  values  obtained  by invoking  clock_getcpuclockid(),  which    represent  the CPU-time clock of a given process. Implementations shall also support the special clockid_t  value CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, which  represents  the  CPU-time  clock of  the  calling process when invoking one of the clock_*() or timer_*() functions.

Given that the user can Is there any real argument against the notion that if `clock_id` is set to `CLOCK_REALTIME`, the system call should be used?

Comment: Since `rtdscp` is a CPU feature, your VM is supposed to make it work.

Comment: How do you know the kernel isn't talking to that driver in order to keep correct the CPU real-time clock read by `rtdscp`?

Comment: I don't know, and that's part of the problem. I have yet to find anything detailing how the kvm-clock source actually works or what it does or how it's enabled in the kernel. There's no kvm module actively loaded. There's nothing indicating I need to load anything. At any rate, if glibc's implementation of  `clock_gettime` can't be configured to not use `rtdscp `, I'd say that's a real problem.

Comment: @Otheus _"... if glibc's implementation of clock_gettime can't be configured to not use rtdscp , I'd say that's a real problem."_ - Why? What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: @marcelm The OS keeps time for a reason. Consider the case when you have a program such as NTP adjusting time. I imagine if it does this, it uses a glibc call to set the time which hopefully will be written in a way to update the CPU with the same information. Now imagine you have a system with 16384 CPU cores. Even if you ignore the logistics of setting the time on all cores, you have huge inter-CPU drift. Now consider the case that you have a hardware clock device; your device driver reads this time via the syscall.... but your library doesn't.

Comment: @Otheus So you don't actually have a problem, you're just trying to invent one ;) . Linux doesn't keep time, the hardware does. Usually, the CPU, using the TSC. So when you `gettimeofday()` into Linux, what Linux does is read the TSC, apply some transformations, return the result. It buys you nothing over doing the `rdtscp` + transformations in userspace, but it does cost a bunch of cycles extra.

Comment: @marcelm Complete bullocks. It's the OS's job to provide an abstraction for hardware services, including the clock. The Linux OS provides such a system call for this very reason. The GNUlibc is cheating.

Comment: 1) are you sure this is related to your problem with the `kvm-clock` driver? (You did say the programs get the correct time)

Comment: 2) You said the code uses "rtdscp". Are you sure that's exactly where the time comes from?

Comment: @ilkkachu Question 1: I have no idea if it's related to kvm-clock driver problem. I suspected at first, then compared the syscall output to glibc call output -- they were the same though the system had a 3 second drift. Question 2: My evidence is circumstantial: (1) `strace` did not indicate a sytemcall, (2) gdb found that the code did an `rtdscp` followed by a bunch of math, and never invoked the `syscall` instruction, which was in fact in the disassembled function. Presumably there is a way to force it to use this call.

Comment: @Otheus Go argue with the Linux and glibc folks then :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the reason you don't see a syscall happening, is that some Linux system calls (esp. those related to time, like `gettimeofday(2)` and `time(2)`) have special implementations through the [vDSO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html), which contains somewhat optimized implementations of some syscalls:

> The "vDSO" (virtual dynamic shared object) is a small shared library
>          that the kernel automatically maps into the address space of all
>          user-space applications.
>
> There are some system calls the
>          kernel provides that user-space code ends up using frequently, to the
>          point that such calls can dominate overall performance.  This is due
>          both to the frequency of the call as well as the context-switch
>          overhead that results from exiting user space and entering the
>          kernel.

Now, the manual mentions that the required information is just placed in memory so that a process can access it directly (the current time isn't much of a secret, after all). I don't know about the exact implementation, and could only guess about the role of the CPU's time stamp counter in the it.

So, it's not really glibc doing an optimization, but the kernel. It can be disabled by setting `vdso=0` on the [kernel command line](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt), and it should be possible to compile it out. I can't find if it's possible to disable it on the glibc side, however (at least without patching the library).

There's a bunch of other information and sources on this [question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938324/what-are-vdso-and-vsyscall).

---

You said in the question:

> After reviewing the latest POSIX draft, part of the answer is clear: there is a way to request the clock from the CPU, but GNU glibc has wrongly forced this implementation on its users.

Which I think is a rather bold statement. I don't see any evidence of "wrongly forcing" anything on users, at least not to their disadvantage. The vDSO implementation is used by almost every Linux process running on current systems, meaning that if it didn't work correctly, some very loud complaints would have been already heard. Also you said yourself that the time received is correct.

The quote you give from the `clock_gettime` manual only seems to mention that the call must support clock id's returned by [`clock_getcpuclockid`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/clock_getcpuclockid), not anything about the behaviour of `CLOCK_REALTIME` or [`gettimeofday`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/gettimeofday).