# Assembly code that print to screen without syscall

Tags: linux, x86, assembly

Is it possible, in Linux, to write an x86 assembly program that print a character to the screen (standard output) **without** the use of any system call?

I think that it is not possible because, in x86 assembly, the input/output operations are priviledge, so it's impossible to run that operation if the CPU is not in RING 0.

Comment: This doesn’t change the answer, but are you specifically asking about the screen, or any standard output? The latter could be a file, a serial port, etc.

Comment: Any standard output, I've wrote the screen only to simplify the question

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Yes - you are correct that OS does prevent user processes to access devices (video in this case) directly.

No - you can send your application into the zero ring. Just present it as a module to the kernel for example. It wont be standard user level application, of course, but it is possible.

Comment: You are right, but I'm talking about standard user application. I want to be sure that is correct that a user application can't print to the screen (or do anything that is under OS exclusive control).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the point of a modern operating system is to provide memory protection and separation between user process as well as useful abstractions like filesystems, pipes and terminals. Part of that is acting as an intermediary between the processes to make sure the rules of those abstractions are enforced. So, pretty much whatever a user process does to interact with anything outside the process has to go through the OS, and system calls are the main way to that.

Now, there are some workarounds. E.g. a shared memory mapping would allow transferring data between processes without involving OS code. Even the kernel provides implementations of some simple system calls without the need to actually call into kernel code, but (AFAIK) those are read-only. See e.g. [Why don't Linux utils use a system call to get the current time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316074/170373)

Even there, the problem is setting up the shared mapping, which is (no surprise) done with a system call. Executing a program file destroys memory mappings, so we can't do that with a regular standalone program. It could be done by having one piece of code set things up, and then call into another which would then only interact through the shared mapping. That second part could be loaded from a separate library file, but I don't know if that counts.